# Unable to display image file in Jupyter markdown cell

Tags: python, image, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

This code in a Markdown cell:

```
<img src="images/grad_summary.png" style="width:600px;height:300px;">
```

works fine in Jupyter browser, but in VS Code with Python extension it does not render at all, only a blank image box is shown.  Both are running in the same conda environment.

This alternate method in a Markdown cell:

```
![title](images/grad_summary.png)
```

also works fine in Jupyter browser but does not render in VS Code with Python ext.

I searched stack overflow, there was something close but it did not address this issue.  Any insights appreciated.

Comment: Both worked for me. I think you have to have a markdown extension installed though. I have "Markdown all in one"

Answer (score 0):

Doing what gnodab said worked for me! Install the "Markdown all in one" extension.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30088648)